# Overriding the AppSettings

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a code snippet like this in my App.config -

```
<appSettings file="..\..\..\master_AppSettings.config"> 
<add key="ApplicationDSN" value="XYZConnectionString" />
</appSettings>
```

In the master_AppSettings.config file I have set "ApplicationDSN" as "ABCConnectionString". Now what I want is the following behavior - If "ApplicationDSN" is not again set in App.config then take the value from master_AppSettings.config file otherwise take the value from App.config. Basically, I want to override the value if it is present in App.config.

The problem is that the above scheme does not seem to work. The C# project is only taking the value from master_AppSettings.config and ignoring if mentioned in App.config.

So, how can I implement my scheme to work? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No can do. Because it is other way round. Mention all your base settings in App.config - whatever you want to override, put it in the external settings file. The external file overrides the App.config.